# How to remove special character in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi guys how to remove \ and / for below link.we are getting problem like unknown escape sequence

```
{"status":"200","description":"OK","count":"4","reg_flag":1,"cars":[],"appointments_count":"0","addbymecars":[{"gallery":[],"imagescount":0,"id":"1924453","mypage_list_flag":0,"appointment_date":"","listing_status":"Active","sellername":"test ","sellernumber":"+918888888888","email":"ufhwifuw@gmail.com","make":"Hyundai","model":"i20","model_type":"Asta 1.4 CRDI","listing_type":"","listing_sorting_order":"","band_color":"","price":"65,59,595\/-","state":"Telangana","city":"Hyderabad","area":"","mfgyear":"2013","color":"Green","owner":"2","user_type":"person","dealer_id":"1503181","isfeatured":"0","fueltype":"Diesel","pincode":"0","mileage":"89,89,898","app_latitude":"","app_longitude":"","certification":"n","certification_text":"","images":{"ldpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg","mdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable100x75.jpg","hdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable150x113.jpg","xhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable200x150.jpg","xxhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable300x225.jpg"},"usedcarshortlist":"0","postingdate":"04-Jan-2016","mobile_link":"http:\/\/testm.cartrade.com\/L1924453","transmission":"Manual"},{"gallery":[],"imagescount":0,"id":"1924742","mypage_list_flag":0,"appointment_date":"","listing_status":"Active","sellername":"yuyu ","sellernumber":"+919898889989","email":"jhhgj@gmail.com","make":"Maruti Suzuki","model":"800","model_type":"AC","listing_type":"","listing_sorting_order":"","band_color":"","price":"15,64,654\/-","state":"Delhi","city":"New Delhi","area":"","mfgyear":"2014","color":"","owner":"1","user_type":"person","dealer_id":"1484907","isfeatured":"0","fueltype":"Petrol","pincode":"110001","mileage":"1,233","app_latitude":"28.6182","app_longitude":"77.2233","certification":"n","certification_text":"","images":{"ldpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg","mdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable100x75.jpg","hdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable150x113.jpg","xhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable200x150.jpg","xxhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable300x225.jpg"},"usedcarshortlist":"0","postingdate":"05-Feb-2016","mobile_link":"http:\/\/testm.cartrade.com\/L1924742","transmission":"Manual"},{"gallery":[],"imagescount":0,"id":"1924641","mypage_list_flag":0,"appointment_date":"","listing_status":"Active","sellername":"vcnvmcx ","sellernumber":"+919812345687","email":"chk@gmail.com","make":"Maruti Suzuki","model":"Alto 800","model_type":"LX","listing_type":"","listing_sorting_order":"","band_color":"","price":"2,50,000\/-","state":"Maharashtra","city":"Mumbai","area":"New Hyderabad","mfgyear":"2015","color":"","owner":"1","user_type":"person","dealer_id":"1503221","isfeatured":"0","fueltype":"Petrol","pincode":"500001","mileage":"50,000","app_latitude":"17.3897","app_longitude":"78.478","certification":"n","certification_text":"","images":{"ldpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg","mdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable100x75.jpg","hdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable150x113.jpg","xhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable200x150.jpg","xxhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable300x225.jpg"},"usedcarshortlist":"1","postingdate":"03-Feb-2016","mobile_link":"http:\/\/testm.cartrade.com\/L1924641","transmission":"Manual"}]}
```

Comment: you want to remove '/' or '\' ?

Comment: yes i want remove \/ and replace /

Comment: If you parse that thing as JSON they will get removed automagically.

Comment: how to remove  double quote in string    like  vikra"marka

Comment: we are using JSON..... but getting nil value

Comment: If you are "using JSON", you may want to show the code and we can try to find the issue.

Comment: json not accepting \/ these character

Comment: that is unlikely the response you are receiving as a response; it seems to be converted to some kinda string representation instead of proper parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this like this:

```
NSString *s = "http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg";
NSString *outcome = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""]
```

Edit: I don't know what you want to have removed. But that's the way to go.

But I think you want "\" to be removed:

```
 NSString *s = "http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg";
 NSString *outcome = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""]
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you may be confusing the output of an NSLog statement with the real string.

Second, it seems that what you have is JSON converted to a string. JSON *needs* the \ where it is. A JSON parser will parse your data just fine. If you managed to remove the \ it wouldn't parse it anymore.

Comment: hi, how to remove  double quote in string